# Parenthesis are not balanced

Tags: c

Why it's not printing "Paranthesis are balanced". It crashes whenever i pass the balance parenthesis like "(2+4)" etc. And works perfectly whenever i pass the unbalance parenthesis like "((3+4(". Here's my code.

```
struct stackADT {
    int count;
    char data[50];
} s;


bool Is_Equal(char b, char c){
    if(b == '(' && c == ')')
            return true;

    if(b == '{' && c == '}')
            return true;


    if(b == '[' && c == ']')
            return true;

    else{
            return false;

  }
}


bool pop(struct stackADT *s, int *num) {
    if (Is_Empty())
        return false;
    else {
        *num = s->data[(s->count) -1];
        (s->count)--;
        return true;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char expression[100];
    int i, len;
    initialize();
    printf("Enter an expression: ");
    scanf("%s", &expression);
    len = strlen(expression);


    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(expression[i] == '(' || expression[i] == '{' || expression[i] == '['){
            push(expression[i]);
        }
            if(expression[i] == ')' || expression[i] == '}' || expression[i] == ']'){

                pop(&s,expression[i]);
        }
    }

    if(Is_Equal(pop(&s, expression[i]), expression[i]))
        printf("Parenthesis are balanced\n");
    else{
        printf("Parenthesis are unbalanced\n");
    }
    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Have you read the comments to your previous question?

Comment: yes, that part is done, but I having issues in figuring out that why it's not printing "Parenthesis are balanced ".

Comment: *Debug it*. Start with a simple `()` case.

Answer (score 1):

in:

```
if(Is_Equal(pop(&s, expression[i]), expression[i]))
```

`i` is larger than `len` (the size of `expression`). And your compiler should have complained because you are pushung a char where a pointer to an int is expected.

So, first turn warnings on.

Comment: I turned on the warnings, but i don't understand what you are saying, elaborate please.

Comment: Paul means, turn on warnings, *then change your code so that it doesn't produce any warnings*, then try to run it. A warning from the compiler means "this is not strictly illegal but is almost certainly not what you mean"

Answer (score 1):

The function `Is_Equal` has the proto type:

```
bool Is_Equal(char b, char c)
              ^^^^^^
              Expects a char
```

The function `pop`has the proto type:

```
bool pop(struct stackADT *s, int *num)
^^^^
Returns a bool
```

So this line has a general problem:

```
    if(Is_Equal(pop(&s, expression[i]), expression[i]))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                bool but char was expected!
```

The same can be said about the `pop` function. It expects a `int*` as second argument but you pass a `char`. For instance here:

```
pop(&s,expression[i]);
```